# What are the use cases for AttachedToParent?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

One of the differences between `Task.Run` and `TaskFactory.StartNew` is the addition of the new `DenyChildAttach` option by default. But `AttachedToParent` was created for a reason. In what situation would you want to use attached child tasks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The use case for `AttachedToParent` is when you have a nested [dynamic task parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx) scenario. That is:

1. You have an algorithm to execute in parallel (that is, CPU code, not I/O operations), **and**
2. The tasks your algorithm must perform vary *while the algorithm is running* (that is, at the time your algorithm starts, it doesn't know how many tasks it needs), **and**
3. There is a hierarchical or parent/child relationship in the completion of these tasks (that is, the "parent" should not be considered complete until all its children are complete, and if any children are failed/canceled, then the parent should be failed/canceled as well, even if its code did not error).

Since the vast majority of concurrency problems are I/O-based (not CPU-based), and since the vast majority of parallelism scenarios are data-based parallelism (not dynamic task parallelism), and since dynamic task parallel problems may or may not have a hierarchical nature, this scenario almost never comes up.

Unfortunately, there is a *logical* parent/child relationship between tasks (including asynchronous tasks), which have caused a lot of developers to incorrectly attempt to use the `AttachedToParent` flag with `async` tasks. Thus, the introduction of the `DenyChildAttach` flag (which prevents `AttachedToParent` from taking effect).

Comment: Hi Stephen! Perhaps, any real use cases of the flag `AttachedToParent` have appeared over the years?

Comment: @RodionMostovoy: My answer is still up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

The only situation I can think of is made obsolete by async-await. E.g. if you want a task to wait on its child tasks you will `await` them.

```
var parentTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));          
    Console.WriteLine("parent task completed");
});
```

But in .Net 4.0 you would have to `Wait()` on them. E.g.

```
var parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000)).Wait();       
    Console.WriteLine("parent task completed");
});
```

Unlike the first example this will block the thread until the child task is complete. With attached tasks we can get the same behaviour like this.

```
var parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent)
    .ContinueWith(antecedent => Console.WriteLine("parent task completed", TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
});
```